# Disabling Chatter Answers

Tags: apex

I got the error message "Error: You can't disable Chatter Answers..."

I have deleted the workflows, pages, and field updates per Salesforce knowledge article but I am unable to delete the trigger because the ChatterAnswers Test class is failing.  So I am stuck.  I can't release any code to our production environment due to these test classes failing. And cant deleted / inactivate the trigger as well.

Comment: What's the error message for the failing test?

Comment: Do you have Communities enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete everything at one time.  Use the force.com IDE to delete all 4 classes and the trigger at once.