# What's with the Chatter Answers test code that's failing?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, chatter-answers

After enabling Chatter Answers, I now have a trigger called chatter_answers_question_escalation_to_case_trigger. The trigger fails test coverage at 35%. What can I do about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a known issue. One of the the possible workarounds is to delete the trigger - even that's a tricky process as you have to delete delete everything at one time. Use the force.com IDE to delete all related classes and the trigger at once. There are some threads like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008pUeIAI) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/disabling-chatter-answers/15529#15529) where this issue has been reported earlier.

Comment: Wouldn't this option only work if you don't plan on using Chatter Answers after enabling (considering you cannot successfully disable it)? I'm just covering bases here for others reading. I don't use chatter answers, but I'm stuck with it since I enabled it already. I'll try this out. I would love to get rid of the trigger. I'll follow up.

Comment: I removed this trigger, and its accompanying test class. Now I have 4 test classes > 80% and near 50 at 100% and I'm still at 65% org code coverage. I'm going to submit a case to sfdc.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a quick fix, edit the trigger to be on one line.  It's completely not advisable, but it gets you out of the dog house.

```
trigger chatter_answers_question_escalation_to_case_trigger on Question (after update) 
{
    for (Question q: Trigger.new) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            if (q.Priority == 'high' && (q.Cases == null || q.Cases.size() == 0) && Trigger.oldMap.get(q.id).Priority != 'high') 
            { 
                q = [select Id, Title, Body, CommunityId, createdById, createdBy.AccountId, createdBy.ContactId from Question where Id = :q.Id]; 
                Case newCase = new Case(Origin='Chatter Answers', OwnerId=q.CreatedById, QuestionId=q.Id, CommunityId=q.CommunityId, Subject=q.Title, Description = (q.Body == null? null: q.Body.stripHtmlTags()), AccountId=q.CreatedBy.AccountId, ContactId=q.CreatedBy.ContactId); 
                insert newCase; 
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            String subjectText = 'Case Escalation exception in site ' + Site.getName(); 
            String bodyText = 'Case Escalation on Question having ID: ' + q.Id + ' has failed with the following message: ' + e.getMessage() + '\n\nStacktrace: ' + e.getStacktraceString();  
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] { Site.getAdminEmail() }; 
            mail.setReplyTo('no-reply@salesforce.com'); 
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Chatter Answers User'); 
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
            mail.setSubject(subjectText); mail.setPlainTextBody(bodyText); 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); 
        }
    }
}
```